# Personal Genomic Data Samples

Tags: genomes, snp, data

a quick question. I am looking for complete personal genomic data of human individuals. The only requirement for the genomic data is that it contains the complete set of SNPs of a human individual. So far I found only one, [a hispanic female](https://my.pgp-hms.org/profile/hu9D75D9).

Are there any similar personal genomic data available on the web?
Any database I can access with a collection of SNPs per individual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.internationalgenome.org) is the link to the [1000 Genomes project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000_Genomes_Project), all the data is available for download. They already have a comprehensive list of SNPs as well.
It is not the only project around but it is definitely the one with more accurate data on so many genomes right now.

Answer (score 1):

Another source would be the [Simons Genome Diversity Project](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/life-sciences/simons-human-diversity-project/) published by [Mallick et al.](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v538/n7624/full/nature18964.html) in 2016. This set covers way more populations than the 1000 Genomes, and therefore includes more overall human genetic diversity, but also has only few individuals per populations (and populations do not overlap with 1000 Genomes as far as I know).

Which database is better for you depends on the actual question.